# WIth the G1 Collector, Can one array object be allocated to different

Tags: java, g1gc

//VM args: -verbose:gc -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseG1GC

```
public static void testAllocation() {
     byte[] allocation1, allocation2, allocation3, allocation4;
    allocation1 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation2 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation3 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation4 = new byte[4 * _1MB];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testAllocation();
}
```

Run the program I got the following result:

[GC pause (G1 Humongous Allocation) (young) (initial-mark), 0.0015208 secs]
   ......

Heap
 garbage-first heap   total 20480K, used 10816K [0x00000007bec00000, 0x00000007bed000a0, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 1024K, 2 young (2048K), 1 survivors (1024K)
 Metaspace       used 3308K, capacity 4496K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 365K, capacity 388K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

=================================================================================

The array size are 2MB or 4MB, the region size is 1MB, Could any one tell me why it used 2 young regions and 1 survivors ?

Comment: Allocated to different what?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are specifying `-XX:SurvivorRatio=8`, but `-XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is on, as such `SurvivorRatio` is simply ignored.

Then, I have explained what some of the lines you see [a bit in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567878/how-to-properly-read-some-parts-of-the-logging-from-gc-with-xlogheap-debug/60567879#60567879).

Anyway, I ran this with `java-13` and Unified Logging, specifically with:

```
"-Xlog:heap*=debug" "-Xlog:gc*=debug"
```

to see what is going on.

From the logs, I see that there are only two GC cycles, as part of this code. *Actually* it's just one, a concurrent cycle, but as part of that cycle, *young* GC is triggered also. Logically, I treat that as a single GC cycle, but GC logs reports as two.

As such your logs will contain:

```
[0.127s][debug][gc,ergo] Request concurrent cycle initiation (requested by GC cause). GC cause: G1 Humongous Allocation
```

*And* also, you will have:

```
[0.133s][info ][gc    ] GC(0) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 7M->6M(20M) 5.753ms
[0.133s][info ][gc,cpu] GC(0) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[0.133s][info ][gc    ] GC(1) Concurrent Cycle
```

Notice how the concurrent cycle is piggy-backed off the young cycle.

---

Now, to answer about the regions.

The `GC (0)` starts with:

```
[0.127s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0)...
[0.127s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) region size 1024K, 1 young, 0 survivors
```

So you start with `1 Young = 1 Eden + 0 Survivors`

Later, there will be a log:

```
[0.133s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Eden regions:     1 -> 0 (9)
[0.133s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Survivor regions: 0 -> 1 (2)
```

As I have explained in the link I gave above, the *next cycle* of young GC will be hinted to use:

```
11 young regions = 9 Eden + 2 Survivor
```

But, as I said there, this is *only* a hint. Since this is a *humongous allocation*, it will actually use less regions as seen by the heap layout when you exit:

```
[0.157s][info ][gc,heap,exit]  garbage-first heap   total 20480K....
[0.158s][info ][gc,heap,exit]  region size 1024K, 2 young 1 survivors
```

The GC has no idea that you only allocate big Objects and it should not use *any* young regions at all and its heuristics still tell to create some young regions. That is why you see those `2 young, 1 survivor`.

But, if you run your code long enough:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        invokeMe();
    }
}

public static int invokeMe() {
    int x = 1024;
    int factor = 2;
    byte[] allocation1 = new byte[factor * x * x];
    allocation1[2] = 3;
    byte[] allocation2 = new byte[factor * x * x];
    byte[] allocation3 = new byte[factor * x * x];
    byte[] allocation4 = new byte[factor * factor * x * x];

    return Arrays.hashCode(allocation1) ^ Arrays.hashCode(allocation2)
        ^ Arrays.hashCode(allocation3) ^ Arrays.hashCode(allocation4);
}
```

You will start seeing entries like:

```
[0.521s][debug][gc,heap] GC(62) Heap before GC invocations=62 
[0.521s][debug][gc,heap] GC(62) region size 1024K, 0 young (0K), 0 survivors (0K)
```

Notice the `0 young, 0 survivor`.