# How to properly read some parts of the logging from GC with "-Xlog:heap*=debug" "-Xlog:gc*=debug"

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, java-9, g1gc

Suppose I have very simple code:

```
public class Sandbox { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        while (true) {
            map.put(new Random().toString(), new Random().nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

It does not matter how "incorrect" it is, but what it does. It produces an `OutOfMemory`, ultimately. I run it with :

```
java -Xms50M -Xmx50M "-Xlog:heap*=debug" "-Xlog:gc*=debug" Sandbox
```

There will be a lot of logging, I will cut them to the most important parts I care about (I also removed some information from some lines for easier reading)

```
*****************************     GC(0)    *********************************

[0.115s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0)
[0.115s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) region size 1024K, 23 young, 0 survivors

[0.127s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Eden regions: 23->0(15)
[0.128s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Survivor regions: 0->3(3)
[0.128s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Old regions: 0->4
[0.128s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Archive regions: 2->2
[0.128s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Humongous regions: 1->1

[0.128s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
[0.128s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) region size 1024K, 3 young, 3 survivors


 *****************************     GC(1)    *********************************

[0.159s][debug][gc,heap] GC(1) Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0)
[0.159s][debug][gc,heap] GC(1) region size 1024K, 18 young, 3 survivors

[0.181s][info ][gc,heap] GC(1) Eden regions: 15->0(1)
[0.181s][info ][gc,heap] GC(1) Survivor regions: 3->3(3)
[0.181s][info ][gc,heap] GC(1) Old regions: 4->10
[0.181s][info ][gc,heap] GC(1) Archive regions: 2->2
[0.181s][info ][gc,heap] GC(1) Humongous regions: 3->3

[0.181s][debug][gc,heap] GC(1) Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0)
[0.181s][debug][gc,heap] GC(1) region size 1024K, 3 young, 3 survivors

*****************************     GC(2)    *********************************

[0.182s][debug][gc,heap] GC(2) Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0)
[0.182s][debug][gc,heap] GC(2) region size 1024K, 4 young, 3 survivors 

[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Eden regions: 1->0(9)
[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Survivor regions: 3->1(1)
[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Old regions: 10->13
[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Archive regions: 2->2
[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Humongous regions: 3->3

[0.190s][debug][gc,heap] GC(2) Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0)
[0.190s][debug][gc,heap] GC(2) region size 1024K, 1 young, 1 survivors
```

What *exactly* do they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have only found two references online that somehow explain this: one [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=GP1wDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA553&dq=%22Eden%20regions:%22%20%22Xlog:gc%22&hl=ro-MD&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4gZWUivznAhVMXq0KHdyCDW8Q6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=Heap%20after%20GC%20invocations&f=false) and the [other here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y11uDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT277&lpg=PT277&dq=%22Eden%20regions:%22%20%22Xlog:gc%22&source=bl&ots=02Zs6qEeoQ&sig=ACfU3U3kX5pJQA4rWHGyGOZtjUlKKjXOzg&hl=ro-MD&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMo5-q3fvnAhXclXIEHSvxCW4Q6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Eden%20regions%3A%22%20%22Xlog%3Agc%22&f=false). Unfortunately, neither of them made much sense, so I had to look at the source code where this is generated to get an understanding.

The first lines:

```
[0.115s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0)
[0.115s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) region size 1024K, 23 young, 0 survivors
```

Tell you that *before* the first invocation of GC (`0`), young space had `23` regions allocated. It also tells you (indirectly) that out of these 23 : `0` were survivor regions, meaning `23` were `Eden` ones.

The next lines:

```
[0.127s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Eden     regions:     23 -> 0 (15)
[0.128s][info ][gc,heap] GC(0) Survivor regions:     0  -> 3 (3)
```

Tell you that *before* the `GC operation`, there were `23` Eden regions. *All* of them were cleared (that `0`) (after all, this is the reason young GC exists). Then it shows that before the GC there were `0` Survivor regions, but as the result of this cycle, `3 Survivor Regions` were generated.

You have to be extra careful what this means. This *does not* show you how many regions will be available to the next cycle, this only shows you the transition that happened.

This "transition" is explained in these logs:

```
[0.128s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
[0.128s][debug][gc,heap] GC(0) region size 1024K, 3 young, 3 survivors
```

Notice how the heap has transitioned to `3 young, 3 survivors` (thus, `0 eden`, all `23` were cleared).

There is another step done afterwards: the total number of regions will be adjusted. How? You can take a look at [source code yourself](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1Policy.cpp#l304), to find out.

Specifically that `(3)` will be computed [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1Policy.cpp#l957) with more details (and very good comments) [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1Policy.cpp#l232), it basically says how many `Survivor Regions` will be available to the next GC cycle. In the majority of cases that `(3)` will be equal to that `->3`, for Survivor Regions.

This "adjustment" is about that `(15)` and `(3)`, which means, the next cycle will have `15 Eden Regions` and `3 Survivor Regions`; also denoted by the *next* cycle's logs, at the very beginning of it.

```
[0.159s][debug][gc,heap] GC(1) Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0)
[0.159s][debug][gc,heap] GC(1) region size 1024K, 18 young, 3 survivors
```

There is one comment I need to make here: these are *hints* to what the GC in the next cycle is suppose to use, they might be ignored (a `humongous allocation` will cause this, for example).

So we can draw a line now. There are two logical pieces in these logs.

- Transition - how young regions changed due to this cycle
- Adjust number of young regions after that transition.

---

Now it should be fairly easy to digest some logs, for example:

```
[0.182s][debug][gc,heap] GC(2) Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0)
[0.182s][debug][gc,heap] GC(2) region size 1024K, 4 young, 3 survivors
```

It *started* with `4 young = 1 Eden + 3 Survivor`

```
[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Eden     regions: 1 -> 0 (9)
[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Survivor regions: 3 -> 1 (1)
```

It *transitioned* to `0 Eden, 1 Survivor`

```
[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Eden     regions: 1 -> 0 (9)
[0.190s][info ][gc,heap] GC(2) Survivor regions: 3 -> 1 (1)
```

It applied heuristic to generate `9 Eden, 1 Survivor` to the next GC cycle.

Comment: Good to see a detailed explanation of the logs. It might take me some time to relate it with an instance in a production environment, but I would keep this starred. Thanks for sharing.